# KCL lease table is not created in dynamo-db after consumer is connected

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, sharding, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl

We have newly created kinesis stream, which causes the below error while trying to connect via KCL in java and the stream is available to put records on the fly.

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.exceptions.internal.KinesisClientLibIOException:
>   Shard [shardId-000000000000] is not closed. This can happen if we
>   constructed the list of shards  while a reshard operation was in
>   progress.

Based on the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-ddb.html)

It says a worker will create while and use **describe stream** to create the lease records and the table.

Hence tried the 
**aws kinesis describe-stream --stream-name name-of-the-stream** 
and it produces

```
{
    "StreamDescription": {
        "Shards": [
            {
                "ShardId": "shardId-000000000000",
                "HashKeyRange": {
                    "StartingHashKey": "0",
                    "EndingHashKey": "340282366920938463463374607431768211455"
                },
                "SequenceNumberRange": {
                    "StartingSequenceNumber": "49603537352759079517281897546367071275105924397167280130"
                }
            }
        ],
        "StreamARN": "arn:aws:kinesis:us-west-2****",
        "StreamName": "***",
        "StreamStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "RetentionPeriodHours": 24,
        "EnhancedMonitoring": [
            {
                "ShardLevelMetrics": []
            }
        ],
        "EncryptionType": "NONE",
        "KeyId": null,
        "StreamCreationTimestamp": 1579767966.0
    }
}
```

However, the lease table in dynamo DB under the same region is missing.
Any suggestions could be helpful.

*Thanks in advance.*